# Navigation Component with Flutter Go Router

Tags: flutter, navigation

I have this layout.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHL4y.png]

my go router code:

```
final appRouter = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => HomePage(key: state.pageKey),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: 'dashboard',
            builder: (context, state) => DashboardPage(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: 'audit',
            builder: (context, state) => const AuditPage(),
          ),
        ]),
  ],
  errorPageBuilder: (context, state) => MaterialPage(
    key: state.pageKey,
    child: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(state.error.toString()),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

How can I do if I want normal navigation just like bottom navigation or tab navitation.
So, when I select each menu, it replaces the green panel with the screen. It may be simple to use state with condition. but it is possible to use with go router. I see nested navigation documentation. Its abit confusing.

***There is something like this provided in AutoRoute package.***

[image]

Comment: Hi, adding an answer even though the question is over a year old so that others that come here with a similar issue can benefit. You want to you a ShellRoute https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html

Comment: @FrankHernandez is this new feature released now?

Comment: It has been available for a few versions now @Sras but you should find it on the current latest version 12.1.1

Comment: @FrankHernandez can you create a sample of this case